# VBA search each cell iteratively for a string

Tags: excel

I'm working on equipment databases for my job, and I'm trying to search for a variable string in each cell of a column, and once that string is found, I need to assign another variable to the value of the cell in the column next to the column I'm searching.
I can perform loops and iterations and if statements, however I'm having a hard time finding a function that would allow me to search specific cells for a string.

Is there any way to specify a search of a cell, sort of like Cells(x,y).find()etc.  or does that not exist?  Also, I've found a lot of documentation on the InStr() function, but that only counts the number of times a string appears in a column, right?  Is there any way to return the row,col numbers of cells that the string is found in?  Thank you for any help you can offer.

```
Sub Trans()
Dim A As Range, r As Range, s As String

Set A = Range("A2:A11")

s = "T1"

For Each r In A
    If InStr(1, r.Value, s) > 0 Then
        i = r.Row
        Cells(i, C) = "here"
    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about potentially using *InStr()*.  Here is a tiny example of searching a column:

```
Sub SeekingHappiness()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range, s As String
    s = "happiness"
    Set A = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each r In A
        If InStr(1, r.Value, s) > 0 Then
            MsgBox r.Address & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

There is also a **.Find()** method that minimizes looping.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand the InStr() function way better now.  Now I'm trying to use the r.Row value to assign values to cells in the same row the string was found, but I keep getting error 1004-object defined error.  The issue is with Cells(r.Row, B)="Value".  Would you know what the issue is with this?

Comment: @raziel3lok  I cannot see your code.  **Update your original Post to include your code.**